# Connect Pentaho to Azure blob storage or ADLS

Tags: azure, validation, pentaho, data-transfer

Is there any way to connect pentaho to Azure Blob Storage or ADLS? Because I am not able to find any option?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file in Azure Blob and Generate SAS token and URL and copy the URL only. In PDI, select Hadoop file input. Double click the Hadoop file input and select local for the Evironment and insert the Azure URL in File/Folder field and that's it. You should see the file in PDI.

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_cloud-data-access/content/authentication-wasb.html

This article explains how to connect the Pentaho Server to a Microsoft Azure HDInsight cluster. [Pentaho supports both the HDFS file system and the WASB (Windows Azure Storage BLOB) extension for Azure HDInsight.](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/8.2/Setup/Configuration/Hadoop_Clusters/Azure_HDInsight)